# Extension for Array with Closures

Tags: arrays, swift, closures, extension-methods

I have an array contained closures with next type of closures:

```
typealias FuncT = (()->Void)
```

I want to add extension method to the array that contains my functions:

```
extension Array where Element : FuncT {
    func execAll() {
        self.forEach { (f) in
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

I get compilation error:

> Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'FuncT'
>   (aka '() -> ()')

How I can add method to a Array contained my functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constraint `where A : B` restricts `A` to subclasses of the *class* `B`, or to types conforming to the *protocol* `B`. Functions types are value types but not classes, and cannot conform to protocols.

What you need is a “same type requirement” `where A == B`. In your case:

```
extension Array where Element == FuncT { ... }
```